# writing DFS iterator for graph

Tags: c++, search, graph, iterator

I am stucked with implementing C++ `iterator` for graph, which is represented by adjacency list. 
So, the idea is that my iterator should go through the graph by using *DFS algorithm*. 
As an example, for ++ iterator goes to the next unvisited vertex for current vertex (like in simple DFS).

My templates for graph vertex and iterator are simple:

```
template < typename VType, typename EType >
struct vertex {
    typedef vertex < VType, EType > graph_vertex;
    vertex (string _name, VType _v_data): name(_name), v_data(_v_data) { }
    typedef pair < graph_vertex* , EType > ve;  

    vector <ve> adj; //adjacency list [ graph_vertex, edge_value ]
    string name;    
    VType v_data;
    bool marked;  // for DFS
};

template < typename VType, typename EType >
class dfs_iterator {
    public:
        dfs_iterator();
        dfs_iterator( graph_vertex* start );
        ~dfs_iterator();
        dfs_iterator(const dfs_iterator& that);

        dfs_iterator& operator = (const dfs_iterator& that) {
            val = that.val;
        }
        dfs_iterator& operator ++ () { } // read down
        dfs_iterator& operator -- () { } // read down
        VType operator * () { return val->v_data; };

        bool operator == (const dfs_iterator& that) const { return val == that.val; }
        bool operator != (const dfs_iterator& that) const { return !(*this == that); }
    private:
        graph_vertex* val;
    };
```

Things that I suppose:

In `struct vertex` should be:

- pointer `graph_vertex*` to the vertex, which was iterated (++'ed) to
  this (current) vertex (to return back from current vertex).
  I will name it `graph_vertex* predecessor_vertex;`
- successor() and predecessor() functions, which will return
        pointers `graph_vertex*` to the next / previous ( for DF-search ) vertices .

  ```
  pseudocode successor(CURR_VERT):
      for every graph_vertex VERT in CURR_VERT->ADJ LIST do {
             if ( VERT not marked )
                  return VERT;
             return successor (predecessor_vertex);
      }
  pseudocode predecessor(CURR_VERT):
       return CURR_VERT->predecessor_vertex;
  ```

  If I think in a correct way, now I got a `++` and `--` for my dfs_iterator ( overloaded functions of ++/-- shall return successor() / predecessor() for current vertex stored in iterator (and of course, change `marked` flag for current vertex )

But I  don't understand how to deal with situation, when user creates a lot of iterators for one graph, then `graph_vertex` info will corrupt because `marked` flags will not respond correctly (one iterator can change it, then second is unable to iterate through this vertex). Should I store a special `vector` of `marked` flags in each iterator, and not in vertex? Or duplicate this information somehow to `graph_vertex` flag ? 
Should I overload some other operators for this iterator ?

Please, give me some tips about my code and such implementation. Do I think in a right way?

*// Actually, I can't find any information about such graph iterator, and I am new in C++.*

Comment: The iterator should not modify the graph. For instance, `bool marked;`   should not be in your vertex class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything related to the algorithm should be in the iterator, and not in the graph. More precisely, your iterator should not modify the state of the graph. Think about your iterator used on a `const` graph. Nothing prevents you from using few data structures in your iterator. A naive approach for instance will be to replace

`bool marked;  // for DFS`

in your class vertex by a map in the iterator itself.

`std::map<struct vertex*, bool> visited_vertices`

Comment: okay. If I have mapped everything, then should I move `precessor/successor` functions from `vertex`  into `iterator` ?

Comment: thank you man. You have really helped me, now I've done this task.